# CSS files and Js files not loading in joomla using https

Tags: javascript, css, https, joomla3.0

Recently I try add https to a Joomla site. 
In https everything was ok, now it’s not loading some CSS files and Js files.
Using the network tab in chrome dev tools I get the following error:
(failed)
net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Other times the some javascripts files don’t load entirely throwing some errors. For example:

> “Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input” in loading
>   jquery.min.js

But when accessing directly the file we can see that the file is loaded entrily. For example:
https://recursosartisticos.madeira.gov.pt/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js
You can see the problem accessing the URL  https://recursosartisticos.madeira.gov.pt or https://recursosartisticos.madeira.gov.pt/administrator

The only thing that I change was adding the following text to the .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_env.c>
     SetEnv HTTPS on
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a network problem, nothing to do with Joomla configuration.